# IdentityServer3 - Forgotten password return to login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, identityserver3

I've got a forgotten password page in IDS3, using the additional links, all working ok.

I want a link from the forgotten password page to return to the login, but whenever I persist the clientId and signin from the initial login, I get an error saying "There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again.".

I'm guessing I need something along the lines of the OWIN extensions listed here, https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/owin.html, but I'm not actively in an authentication flow.

Any help or points appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand, Forgotten password feature should be implemented external to the identity server(I think you have already done that part). So when the user is redirected to that forgot password page(not related to identity server), that page has no idea which application the user tried to log into. So you need to somehow persist that information before redirection and access it from forgot password page(maybe using a cookie or query string or just hardcode the application url[if you have only one application])